What is the view of Prosperity in Islam (both individual as well as community)?
by prosperity i mean economical, educational, intellectual and sociological prosperity.
I, more often than not, see sheikhs discouraging the worldly pursuit, but the "wordly" has both good and bad isn't it ? We have a state-of-art field of healthcare today and why would anyone discourage it?
How would a society improve if people stopped being ambitious about the Dunya?
